# Strophe, backbonejs and jquery-mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, strophe

I want to build a MVC structured mobile app with backbonejs. I searched the web for information and I only found the strophe backbone plugins for:

```
strophe.pubsub.js
strophe.forms.js
strophe.vcard.js
strophe.private.js
strophe.roster.js
```

Can I run into problems with using backbone.js and Strophe together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably referring to my own [strophe.plugins](https://github.com/ggozad/strophe.plugins). Those will of course work fine out of the box, in addition they are fully test-covered. You can of course use any other plugin with Strophe, it does not collide with Backbone in any way.

Keep in mind strophe.plugins while independently working, were written to be used together with [Backbone.xmpp](https://github.com/ggozad/Backbone.xmpp). I wrote that library to allow you to sync your Backbone models/collections with XMPP PubSub nodes, giving you real-time events on all your clients.

Here's a [demo](https://vimeo.com/40685900) of how that works in practice with two clients.

Comment: Well, I actually started to code the app without backbone.js and came across this library which is a whole lot different. I wonder if this scenario will work better with bbjs if I take your todo app and go a step further: If a collection node has different todo-leaf nodes then I first request those from server on pageTodos, then I select a particular todo-list item and navigate to pageTodoList. Then I navigate back to pageTodos and select a different todo-list. After that the pageTodoList will be loaded with browser cached items from the first todo list.

Comment: In jquery I would remove all list items on pageTodoList before I navigate back to pageTodos, so that the list items are removed from the DOM. But then I have to fetch all the items again if I want to see the items from the first todo-list I selected. What happens if I use backbone.js? Do I still have to remove all items on pageTodoList when I navigate back to pageTodos and refetch them from the server if I need it later?...My Example: pageTodos (shows collections of different todo lists), pageTodoList (contains items of a particular todo list which is a leaf node).

Comment: You can do all that with Backbone without XMPP. If XMPP is not a necessary part of your app and this is your first Backbone do it without to start. There are also Views available to manage most of what you describe, but it's hard to understand. You do not need to fetch multiple times, you can keep data in memory. It's a single-page-app after all.

Comment: Sure but I'm coding a kind of forum. So it's actually there is a page with different questions and a page with questions which are leaf nodes with answers as items :-).  I have different js files now for every page and now it looks pretty ok.. Do you think it's better to do it with backbone? Because the app will grow and also include geolocation, pep, MUCs, messaging and more. Therefore this could get really wild without a nice structure...

Comment: I would definitely recommend Backbone, I am using it in production and extremely happy.

Comment: I got your plugins to work with require.js but I can't get the community strophe.plugins to work with the $.Deferred d.done() or Callback functions?

Answer (score 3):

No problems using the libraries together.

About 12 months ago, I was part of a small team who used Backbone.js and strophe to implement a one page social networking web app using xmpp / ejabberd as the primary messaging platform.... we ended up redesigning it, replacing ejabberd for a custom RESTful api (http://beta.playup.com).

There are a few issues you need to think about - esp when writing a one page app, such as connection management. As you are creating a stophe connection client side, you need a way to re-connect the users account on page refresh (as the js is obviously reloaded).

We also ran into memory leak problems. Be careful when throwing custom events in Backbone Views... as you will need to manually unbind them when you are done with a view. If you don't the view remains active through the bound event, and is not GC'd. This means you probably have to introduce a bit of a lifecycle in your app.

Generally speaking though, this will only be a problem if you are doing a web app of some size.